# Linux c++: Reading data from serial device

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send data between an arduino and an raspberry pi.

It all works execpt that `read(usb, &buf, 1);` is not returning 0 when no more data is avaliable.
In the description of the function it states:

```
Read NBYTES into BUF from FD. Return the
number read, -1 for errors or 0 for EOF.
```

But it never returns 0;

I'm using this simple code for the arduinio.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

bool blinking = false;
bool led_on = false;
int target_time;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
  }
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  char c;
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    c = Serial.read();
    switch (c) {
    case '0':
      // stop blinking
      blinking = false;
      if (led_on) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
      }
      Serial.write("A", 1);
      break;
    case '1':
      // start blinking
      if (blinking == false) {
        blinking = true;
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        led_on = true;
        target_time = millis() + 100; // turn off in 1 tenth of a second (100 milliseconds)
      }
      Serial.write("ABC\0", 4);
      break;
    default:
      Serial.write("E", 1);
      break;    
    }
  } else if (blinking) {
    if (millis() >= target_time) {
      if (led_on) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        led_on = false;
        target_time = millis() + 100; // turn on in 1 tenth of a second (100 milliseconds)
      } else {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        led_on = true;
        target_time = millis() + 100; // turn off in 1 tenth of a second (100 milliseconds)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the function in the code of the pi

```
int readWhole(int usb, char *response){
    int n = 0,
        spot = 0;
    char buf = '\0';

    memset(response, '\0', sizeof response);

    while (1) {
        cout << "read\n";
        n = read(usb, &buf, 1);    
        cout << "n = " << n << "\n"; 
        usleep(100 * 1000);
        if (n == -1) {
            if (errno != EAGAIN) {
                fprintf(stderr, "read() failed: (%d) %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }
            // errno == EAGAIN, loop around and read again
        } else {
            if (n == 1) {
                sprintf( &response[spot], "%c", buf );
                spot += n;
                cout << "got something: " << buf << "\n";
            }else{ // 0 == End Of File
                break;
            }
            // read 0 bytes, loop around an read again
        }        
    }
    return spot;
}
```

The output I get

```
read
n = -1
read
n = 1
got something: A
read
n = 1
got something: B
read
n = 1
got something: C
read
n = 1
got something: 
read
n = -1
read
n = -1
read
```

Comment: A serial port isn't like a file, there's no "end of file", it's only an unending stream of bytes.

Comment: ok thx, so there is no way to see if data is avalable and read it all?

Comment: It kind of depends on the hardware. If the data carrier detect is connected on both ends it might be possible to use. Otherwise you need to implement your own protocol to handle message flow in software.